# DEBUG MAGENTO ERROR <jstranslator></jstranslator>

Tags: xml, debugging, magento-1.9, sitemap

I was having an error on line 510 on Config.php in the folder lib\Varien\Simplexml. 
I've added a code to see which was the error in detail and the new error is that.

```
2017-12-06T23:10:45+00:00 DEBUG (7): XML_ERROR: <?xml version="1.0"?><jstranslator></jstranslator>
2017-12-06T23:11:39+00:00 DEBUG (7): XML_ERROR: <config/>
2017-12-06T23:15:26+00:00 DEBUG (7): XML_ERROR: <config/>
2017-12-06T23:19:49+00:00 DEBUG (7): XML_ERROR: <config/>
```

The error is generating when the xml map is generated. 
Do you have some ideas where to correct this error? In which file I need to search and what is needed to be corrected?

Comment: I'm on almost the same problem... (`DEBUG (7): XML_ERROR: <config/>`) and (`Entity: line 18: parser error : Premature end of data in tag config line 17  in magentopath/lib/Varien/Simplexml/Config.php on line 510`) did you solve it?

Comment: no I'm sorry :(